# Highlight a single line in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextView` which has a `NSAttributedString` with two line breaks between each lines. I am trying to highlight a single line in the textview. I can simply highlight a sentence in the textview without any problem. But, I need to highlight the sentence from the start of the line (left side of the textview) to the end of the line (right side of the textview)

I have used the following code to highlight a line which is from this [Github Sample](https://github.com/liyong03/iOSDemos/blob/master/TextKit/TextKitNotepad-starter/TextKitNotepad/SyntaxHighlightTextStorage.m). As each lines have two line breaks, I thought after highlighting the actual sentence I can also get the previous and next newline characters and highlight them too. But the results are not like I wanted.

[image]

```
 // 1. create some fonts
UIFontDescriptor* fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor
                                    preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor* boldFontDescriptor = [fontDescriptor
                                        fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
UIFont* boldFont =  [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:boldFontDescriptor size: 0.0];
UIFont* normalFont =  [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];

if (!_highlightedWorld) {
    _highlightedWorld = @"";
}

// Search for the highlighted world by using regex and highlight
NSString* regexStr = _highlightedWorld;
NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:regexStr
                              options:0
                              error:nil];

// Highlighted attributes (Cyan font color, Bold)
NSDictionary* boldAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : boldFont,
                                  NSBackgroundColorAttributeName    :   [UIColor cyanColor]};
//Normal attributes
NSDictionary* normalAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : normalFont,
                                    NSBackgroundColorAttributeName    :   [UIColor whiteColor] };

// If the textview has multiple matches, iterate over each match, and highlight each.
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:[_backingStore string]
                        options:0
                          range:searchRange
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match,
                                  NSMatchingFlags flags,
                                  BOOL *stop){

                         // Highlight the actual line
                         NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
                         [self addAttributes:boldAttributes range:matchRange];

                         // Get the newline after the highlighted sentence, and highlight it
                         // Check if we reached the end
                         if (matchRange.location+matchRange.length < [_backingStore string].length) {
                             [self addAttributes:boldAttributes range:NSMakeRange(matchRange.location+matchRange.length, 1)];
                         }
                         // Get the newline before the highlighted sentence, and highlight it
                         // Check if we reached the beginning
                         if (matchRange.location != 0) {
                             [self addAttributes:boldAttributes range:NSMakeRange(matchRange.location-1, 1)];
                         }

                         // 4. reset the style to the original
                         if (NSMaxRange(matchRange)+1 < self.length) {
                             [self addAttributes:normalAttributes
                                           range:NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(matchRange)+1, 1)];
                         }
                     }];
```

Comment: Is your text always a shopping list, centre aligned with those carriage returns?

Comment: @Wain Not a shopping list, but sentences, centre aligned with two carriage return.

Comment: May I ask, how do you decide on which line to be highlighted?

Comment: The user touches a random location in the TextView, then I find the exact Sentence in that location using the touch location.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you don't use a text view for this. What you have is a list, so using a table or collection view is much better suited to this use case. They will make handling device width and item selection effectively trivial. They also allow you to add other styling around the items (which may be handy).

I haven't needed to do it before, but at the moment with a text view I imagine you'll need to look at how the text is placed into the layout and I expect you'll need to do the centre alignment explicitly so you can select the padding on either side without cascading to the previous or next line. This is far from trivial.

I'm interested to know if there's a simple solution for the text view issue, but it really seems like the wrong view to use for the data, display and user interaction you're looking for.

Comment: Nice suggestion about the Table View, but for some reasons I have to stick with the textview. Because I have options to find/replace, edit text...

Comment: I can try to explicitly align the text in the centre like you are saying, but selecting the padding on either side is the problem. I don't have any idea to do that. Can you help me?

Comment: it's hard, you need to work out how many characters fit on the width of the view. text search and editing can work fine in a table view, the table even has an editing mode you can work with and cells explicitly know about editing...

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how to explain this but I believe it has something to do with \n and \r interpretation by the iOS.

I am guessing you might have created the line gap by either using two \r or two \n i.e

```
NSString *text = @"Shopping List\n\n1. Cheese\n\n2. Biscuits\r\r3 Sausages\n\n4. IMPORTANT Cash for going out!\n\n5. -potatoes-\n\n6. Acopy of iOS6 by tutorials\n\n7. A new iPhone\n\n8. A present for mum";
```

OR

```
NSString *text = @"Shopping List\n\n1. Cheese\n\n2. Biscuits\n\n3 Sausages\n\n4. IMPORTANT Cash for going out!\n\n5. -potatoes-\n\n6. Acopy of iOS6 by tutorials\n\n7. A new iPhone\n\n8. A present for mum";
```

Both the ways your code to highlight the line produces the same output similar to yours.

But, if you replace the 2nd '\n' or '\r' with '\r\n' i.e

```
NSString *text = @"Shopping List\n\n1. Cheese\n\n2. Biscuits\r\r\n3 Sausages\n\n4. IMPORTANT Cash for going out!\n\n5. -potatoes-\n\n6. Acopy of iOS6 by tutorials\n\n7. A new iPhone\n\n8. A present for mum";
```

Or

```
NSString *text = @"Shopping List\n\n1. Cheese\n\n2. Biscuits\n\r\n3 Sausages\n\n4. IMPORTANT Cash for going out!\n\n5. -potatoes-\n\n6. Acopy of iOS6 by tutorials\n\n7. A new iPhone\n\n8. A present for mum";
```

then you get the desired result.

Comment: Looks like you don't understand my question.

Comment: @RamarajT: I was able to highlight a single line using your code snippet when I used the "\n\r\n" to get two line breaks instead of using "\n\n" or "\r\r".